# Web Scraping issue using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[Web scraping issue (screen shot attached)](https://www.ayurveda.com/resources/articles/ayurveda-a-brief-introduction-and-guide)

```
def get_text(value):
tdlist = []
for i in soup.findAll(value): # Reduce data to those with html tag 
    if i.text != "":
        text = i.text
        text = text.strip()
        if '\n' not in text: # Remove unnecessary data
            tdlist.append(text)
return tdlist

Master_df = pd.DataFrame()
logs = []

hh = 0
for tag in df_F['Value']:  

    print(hh)
    hh =  hh + 1

    try:
        url = 'https://www.ayurveda.com' + tag

        #weblink to scrape
        html = urlopen(url)
        y = html.read()

        # Page title is:  Scraping 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(y, 'html.parser') # Parse resulting source

        c_list = []
        Title = []


        for value in ['p']:
            c_list = get_text(value)

        for tes in soup.findAll('h1'):
            Title = tes.text

        com_list = c_list
        com_list = '. '.join(com_list)
        com_list = com_list.replace('..',". ")

        com_list1 = Title

        df_each = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["URL","Title","Content","Category","Website"],index = range(0,1))

       df_each["URL"] = url
       df_each["Content"] = com_list
       df_each["Title"] = com_list1
       df_each["Category"] = 'Ayurveda'
       df_each["Website"] = 'Ayurveda'

       Master_df = Master_df.append(df_each)
   except Exception as e:
       print("Hey!, check this :",str(e))
       logs.append(str(e))
```

#

[Trying to download the content in the website. These are 2 important information downloading from website.

1) Title in a column (marked in 'title') - This is clear. I get right information
2) Content in another column (that is marked 'p') - I have problem in getting these information

below are the information from website :

### Below line I could scrape (marked in bold and italic)

***"by Vasant Lad, BAM&S, MASc"***

### Below line I couldn't scrape (marked in and italic)

*Ayurveda is considered by many scholars to be the oldest healing science. In Sanskrit, Ayurveda means “The Science of Life.” Ayurvedic knowledge originated in India more than 5,000 years ago and is often called the “Mother of All Healing.” It stems from the ancient Vedic culture and was taught for many thousands of years in an oral tradition from accomplished masters to their disciples. Some of this knowledge was set to print a few thousand years ago, but much of it is inaccessible. The principles of many of the natural healing systems now familiar in the West have their roots in Ayurveda, including Homeopathy and Polarity Therapy.*

.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHLXW.png)

Comment: This is not a candidate for good SO question. Avoid posting images, add some text to  your question, add what problems you are facing and what is expected output

Comment: And what is your question? [Edit] it and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried and any research, and show your results as _text_.

Comment: You also need to fix your indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you do not get the paragraph is because of this line here:

```
if '\n' not in text:
```

The paragraph you want:

```
'Ayurveda is considered by many scholars to be the oldest healing science. In Sanskrit, Ayurveda means “The Science of Life.” Ayurvedic knowledge originated\n    in India more than 5,000 years ago and is often called the “Mother of All Healing.” It stems from the ancient Vedic culture and was taught for many\n    thousands of years in an oral tradition from accomplished masters to their disciples. Some of this knowledge was set to print a few thousand years\n    ago, but much of it is inaccessible. The principles of many of the natural healing systems now familiar in the West have their roots in Ayurveda, including\n    Homeopathy and Polarity Therapy.'
```

HAS `\n` so it does not append that text to your `tdlist`. When you use `.strip()`, it will only remove those new lines and white spaces at the beginning and end of the string. So you'll need to find another condition.

So you could just add an extra condition that grabs that specific content that follows the tag `<p class="bitter">`

I am assuming all the the links are following that format.

Change your function:

```
def get_text(value):
    tdlist = []
    for i in soup.findAll(value): # Reduce data to those with html tag 
        if i.text != "":
            text = i.text
            text = text.strip()
            if '\n' not in text or i.find_previous(value).attrs == {'class': ['bitter']}: # Remove unnecessary data
                tdlist.append(text)
    return tdlist
```

**Output:**

```
print (c_list)
['by Vasant Lad, BAM&S, MASc', 'Ayurveda is considered by many scholars to be the oldest healing science. In Sanskrit, Ayurveda means “The Science of Life.” Ayurvedic knowledge originated\n    in India more than 5,000 years ago and is often called the “Mother of All Healing.” It stems from the ancient Vedic culture and was taught for many\n    thousands of years in an oral tradition from accomplished masters to their disciples. Some of this knowledge was set to print a few thousand years\n    ago, but much of it is inaccessible. The principles of many of the natural healing systems now familiar in the West have their roots in Ayurveda, including\n    Homeopathy and Polarity Therapy.', 'Copyright © 2006, Vasant Lad, MASc, and The Ayurvedic Institute. All Rights Reserved.', 'Copyright © 2006, Vasant Lad, MASc, and The Ayurvedic Institute. All Rights Reserved.']
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I removed the line that had "\n", it solved the problem. Thanks Again !